# Change Wordpress REST response

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

I have a plugin that puts custom post types onto a map. It uses Leaflet and specifies a REST API link as the source of its data. A map is displayed with a number of location markers and when clicked a details box pops up with the name of what's at that location and there's a hyperlink in this details box which when clicked takes the user to another page on the site. Here's what is specified as the data-endpoint source:

```
http://rd-dev.local/wp-json/citadela-directory/map-data/points/citadela-item?dataType=markers&category=&location=&only_featured=0
```

This call returns JSON that looks like this:

```
{"total":40,"points":[{"track":[],"coordinates":{"longitude":14.726660728455,"latitude":46.813816070557003},"title":"Name of place","permalink":"http:\/\/rd-dev.local\/item\/something\/","address":"Address, line 2, Someplace, Some Country","image":"http:\/\/rd-dev.local\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/12\/0b-1-150x150.jpeg","postType":"citadela-item","faIcon":"fas fa-circle","color":"#0085ba"}, ... etc
```

Part of each record in the response is a link to a url on the site, which the user clicks to see the detail:

```
http:\/\/rd-dev.local\/item\/something
```

I want to change the page that users see when they click a location so it occurred to me that one way, and which at my level of knowledge is probably the simplest, is to alter the JSON response that Wordpress gives. Specifically, i want to change all occurrences of "item" to a something different.

Is there a way to change the JSON stream as it is sent out by the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I searched for register_rest_route occurrences in the source files and was able to find one for this particular route. The register_rest_route call includes a callback function where the response is constructed. It was then a case of putting that response through text replacement calls.